# Undo WooCommerce CSV import

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, import, csv

I've done a CSV import through the WooCommerce import function. Unfortunately, there's something what went wrong. By now, almost all products don't show any data as it has somehow been overwritten.

I'm running a webshop so this is kind of a huge problem. I've been searching for a solution everywhere but can't find the which makes me get back my original data from before.

Unfortunately I haven't made a back-up before doing the CSV import. I'm praying for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have backup and you need to restore or undo your changes then there is only one way. You have to contact your hosting provider, ask them if they have old database backup. Generally they keep backups. If they will have then request them to restore.

Hope this helps!